# jQuery - check navigation select list url values against current url and set as selected

Tags: jquery

I have a select list used as the main navigation for mobile visitors. The structure is as follows:

```
<select id="nav">
<option value="http://somesite.com/url_1">Page 1</option>
<option value="http://somesite.com/url_2">Page 2</option>
<option value="http://somesite.com/url_3">Page 3</option>
<option value="http://somesite.com/url_4">Page 4</option>
</select>
```

How can I check the current page url against those in the select list, and if one matches, set that as the selected option? I'm guessing it's gonna be something kind of like this:

```
var url = window.location;
$("#nav option").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(url === value) {
        $(this).val('selected','selected');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery attribute selectors:

```
$("#nav option[value='" + window.location + "']").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Bingo, short and sweet. I kinda had something like that floating around in my head too but couldn't quite grab it!

Answer (score 2):

`selected` is a property, you are setting a new value, you can use `prop` and `filter` methods.

```
var url = window.location.href;
$("#nav option").filter(function() {
    return this.value === url;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

You can also use attribute selector, but `filter` method is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
$(this).val('selected','selected');
```

Into

```
$(this).prop('selected',true);
```

So finally (option 1)

```
$("#nav option").each(function() {
    if(window.location === $(this).val()) {
        $(this).val('selected','selected');
    };
});
```

Or easier (option 2)

```
$("#nav option[value='" + document.location + "']").prop("selected", true);
```